# Google Optimize A/B testing freezes the homepage

Tags: google-analytics, a-b-testing, google-optimize

I'm trying to run 4 A/B tests using Google Optimize, on the same domain. The test should exclude themselves via the targeting, however, in most cases when I access the homepage (see: test 1a, 1b below), the page freezes. The test setup follows.

**Variants for all tests:**

```
+---------------------+-------------------------+
|      Original       |        Option A         |
+---------------------+-------------------------+
| https://example.com | https://example.com?v=b |
+---------------------+-------------------------+
```

**Configuration for each test:**

Test 1a (English, homepage)

```
+---------------------+------------------------------------+
|    Should run on    |             Targeting              |
+---------------------+------------------------------------+
| https://example.com | * URL matches: https://example.com |
+---------------------+------------------------------------+
```

Test 1b (German, homepage)

```
+------------------------+---------------------------------------+
|     Should run on      |               Targeting               |
+------------------------+---------------------------------------+
| https://example.com/de | * URL matches: https://example.com/de |
+------------------------+---------------------------------------+
```

Test 2 (EN + DE, document page) - excludes Test 1a and Test 1b

```
+------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|              Should run on               |                                  Targeting                                   |
+------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| https://example.com/courses/viewfile/123 | * URL contains: https://example.com                                          |
| https://example.com/kurse/vorschau/123   | * URL contains any of: viewfile, vorschau                                    |
|                                          | * Path starts with any of: /courses, /kurse                                  |
|                                          | * URL does not end with any of: https://example.com, https://example.com/de  |
+------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Test 3 (EN + DE, course page, university page) - excludes Test 1a, 1b, and 2

```
+------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|              Should run on               |                                  Targeting                                   |
+------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| https://example.com/courses/789          | * URL contains: https://example.com                                          |
| https://example.com/kurse/789            | * URL doesn't contain any of: viewfile, vorschau                             |
| https://example.com/universities/456     | * Path starts with any of: /courses, /kurse, /universities, /unis            |
| https://example.com/unis/456             | * URL does not end with any of: https://example.com, https://example.com/de  |                             
+------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

The other URLs can be accessed with no problems, but it seems that the test configuration somehow "kill" my homepage.

Any ideas?

Comment: What does "kill your homepage" actually mean?   Is your home page no longer accessible?    I don't understand.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller When I access the homepage, the page "freezes" - it doesn't load; Chrome displays a message that the page cannot be displayed, developer tools are inactive, there's no specific error shown. As soon as I end the homepage experiments, the page works, so the assumption is that all the (redirect) experiments are somehow conflicting.